# How to get information during evaluation of a Mathematica script?

Tags: scripting

I have a Mathematica script

```
table=ParallelTable[f[u],{u,0,40,.5}]
Export["filename.csv",table]
```

that computes and exports a table of a rather complicated function f. I execute it using the "math -script table.m&" command. 
As it takes a very long time to calculate this table, I would like to abort the calculation.

Is there any way, to obtain the information that has already been calculated so far?

Comment: +1 I don't think so... but if there is a way, I would like to know about it.